# Copy one ndf file to another SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I have database that contain like 30 .NDF files each one size (10GB-100GB) 
to be clear the ndf files name like that :

```
phone_start_with_1.ndf
phone_start_with_2.ndf
phone_start_with_44.ndf
phone_start_with_371.ndf
```

phone_start_with_1.ndf contains phone numbers starting with (1)

Is there any way to copy one of this (`.ndf`) files and the main (`.mdf`) file to another server ?

I don't want to copy all the files (4TB) for only (100GB) and the query it will take like for ever

Comment: I guess you could restored the copy of the database and remove all the structures that you don't need and create a backup of that copy

Comment: You can do file level [backup and restore...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-files-and-filegroups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: fyi each ndf file is for a table in that database 
do you mean backup the table that I want ?

Comment: You'll backup the actual file...see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-files-and-filegroups-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What is the objective? Transferring data? You can copy the data out of the database using BCP or SSIS. You can't just copy the MDF and _one_ NDF. You need all of the database files to have a functioning database.